# I have an array of objects and want to combine them into one object IF the one of the keys match (without overwriting the initial properties)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects and want to combine them into one object IF the one of the keys match(in this case the "date" key)

```
    Array [
  Object {
    "date": "2020-07-14",
    "finishTime": "22:00",
    "startTime": "13:30",
  },
  Object {
    "date": "2020-07-14",
    "finishTime": "12:00",
    "startTime": "08:00",
  },
]
```

Expected output should be

```
 Array [
  Object {
    "date": "2020-07-14",
    "finishTime": ["22:00", "12:00"]
    "startTime": ["13:30", "08:00"]
  },
```

Comment: Yes that's the response I'm getting from the API (a key in the form of a string) but I need to mutate the property (in this case the startTime and finishTime properties) by comparing if the two date strings ('2020-07-14') are the same. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Do you want to group them by one matching field or by any matching fields? What happens if in your example there is another object whose `date` is equal to `2020-06-07` and `startTime` is `13:30`?

Comment: Good question. This is handled on the client-side so multiple shifts with the same start time cannot be selected. So there can be no duplicate date starts.

Comment: What happens if an entry doesn't have another similar entry, should it's values be left as a normal ? or should it be turned into an array with a single value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a generic `groupBy` function that will combine objects by field. Example:

```js
const data = [
    {
      "date": "2020-07-14",
      "finishTime": "22:00",
      "startTime": "13:30",
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-07-14",
      "finishTime": "12:00",
      "startTime": "08:00",
    }
];


function groupBy(array, property) {
    const temp = {};
    for (const item of array) {
        const propValue = item[property];
        if (!temp.hasOwnProperty(propValue)) {
            temp[propValue] = {
                [property]: propValue 
            };
        }

        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
            if (key === property) continue;

            temp[propValue][key] = (temp[propValue][key] || []).concat(value);
        }
    }
    return Object.values(temp);
}

console.dir(groupBy(data, 'date'));
```

Output:

```js
[
    {
        date: "2020-07-14",
        finishTime: ["22:00", "12:00"],
        startTime: ["13:30", "08:00"],
    }
]
```

My example uses the `ES6` syntax, if you need to, you can easily remake this code into `ES5`. Also, my code is written in an imperative style, it can be rewritten using `reduce` and `forEach` if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Logic behind the solution:

1. Create a new empty array (call it *Y*) where we will store the "compact" solution.
2. Cycle thru all elements of the original array(call it X).
3. Check if the current element (from *X*) already is in the array *Y*, (find the index from *Y* so the element can be updated).
4. If the index is equal to *-1* there is no element so we add it to *Y*.
5. Otherwise (the element already exists in *Y*) we retrieve the element using the index (greater that -1) -> update (with push) the finish and start time -> rewrite the updated *found_element* into *Y* using the index found before.

Here is a working example:

```js
// DATA
const data = [
  {
    "date": "2020-07-14",
    "finishTime": "22:00",
    "startTime": "13:30",
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-07-14",
    "finishTime": "12:00",
    "startTime": "08:00",
  }
];

// NEW_DATA
const new_data = [];

data.forEach(element => {
  const index = new_data.findIndex(el => el.date === element.date);
  
  if(index === -1) {
    // Not Found
    new_data.push({
      "date": element.date,
      "finishTime": [element.finishTime],
      "startTime": [element.startTime],
    });
  } else {
    // Found
    let found_element = new_data[index];
    
    found_element.finishTime.push(element.finishTime);
    found_element.startTime.push(element.startTime);
    
    new_data[index] = found_element;
  }
});

console.log(`NEW DATA: ${JSON.stringify(new_data)}`);
```

Hope it helps :)

PS: This is a very basic solution, you must implement some sort of error checking and type checking. I suggest you to use Typescript :)

PS.PS: As you can see the original data array has not been changed :)